# Querying catalog using a custom date index

Tags: plone

I build a new content-type by Archetypes. This content-type has a date field (datatermine) which is also (customizing the catalog via catalog.xml) a catalog index.

I'm trying to set a browser page with a list of all of the objects with datatermine >= today.

So in my .py I put:

```
[..]
now = DateTime()
query = {'datatermine':{'query':[now,],'range':'min'}}
brains = self.portal_catalog(**query)
```

Brains returns empty. Objects are indexed in catalog properly.

What's wrong?
Vito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: the Index must be (obviously) a DateIndex and not a FieldIndex.